# How to import William Chart into Android Studio Project?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to use William Charts for an Android Studio Project of mine but can't seem to import it. I downloaded the WilliamChart-master zip from [github](https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart), and tried to import it. I'd like to know step by step from download to beeing able to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now use it as a gradle dependency. Take a look at the [Usage](https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart/wiki/%281%29-Usage) wiki page.

Comment: All I needed to do was add `compile 'com.diogobernardino:williamchart:2.2'` to my **app**'s **build.gradle** `dependencies {...}` section.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. unzip WilliamChart-master.zip
2. rename the "library" directory in the WilliamChart-master to "WilliamChart"
3. copy "WilliamChart" directory to your project directory
4. modify `settings.gradle` in your project derectory: `include ':app', ':WilliamChart'`
5. add this to your build.gradle: `compile project(':WilliamChart')`

Comment: this results in compilation error: project_path\WilliamChart\build.gradle Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'android-maven' not found.